# Validating Carrierwave size of upload

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

I am validating the size of a Carrierwave upload. It works very well on localhost but on the server (Amazon EC2) I get the following errors when i try to upload a file bigger than 1MB (which is the limit):

```
POST http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/authors/484.js  /authors/484.js:1
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL data:text/html,chromewebdata from frame with URL http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of ''. Protocols must match.
 default.js:17

484.js /authors POST (failed) Pending Other 13 B 0 B 1.0 min
data:image/png;base… GET Success image/png  data:text/html,chromewebdata:159 Parser 0 B 2.3 KB 0 ms 0 0 ms
```

In the line default.js:17 , where the error happens I see JQuery code (minified)

This is how I am validating the image:

```
  mount_uploader :image_one, AuthorPixUploader
  validates :image_one, 
    :file_size => { 
      :maximum => 1.megabytes.to_i 
    }
```

Any help? I think that it fails before the fails arrive to the server. I dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was setting client_max_body_size in nginx.conf on the server.

I added this line to the server block:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've figured out a solution to your problem, but I had a similar one recently and came across this official CarrierWave tutorial on how to validate file size properly on the server side...

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size